# JQuery Autocomplete results override by the frame

Tags: jquery, iframe, autocomplete, frame

I have two frames in a page top and bottom. Inside the top frame JQuery auto complete list loads. But out of 10 suggestions i can see only 2 are visible, rest of the 8 being override by the bottom frame.

The difficult part when i choose something from autocomplete it loads the data in the top frame. Client doesn't want to change the frameset design.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frameset page</title>
</head>
<frameset rows = "25%, *">
  <frame src ="autocomplete.html" />
  <frame src ="bottom.html" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the client by any chance [this guy](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/I-am-right-and-the-entire-Industry-is-wrong.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

> Client doesn't want to change the frameset design.

Then you're stuck.
You cannot escape the frame.